# loading disk cache in offline mode

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I have read apple's document and find that disk cache is available from ios5.When a instance
 of UIWebView starts load with the internet cut,the method `- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` in NSURLCache return a value that is not nil.But the webView still fails to load.
         It seems that the web content is cached but iOS doesn't use it in offline mode,and only gives an error saying that the internet is off.
        I found that iOS caches data in a file named "Cache.db" in the cache directory.Is there any 
way to let UIWebView load the data in this file in offline mode?
          Many thanks.

Comment: am facing the same issue..! let me know if u found solution for this.

Comment: I find the best solution rob's.He mainly implements NSURLProtocol,intercepts the connection there,and saves the downloaded data into the disk for cache.Rob has implemented it and you can get the source  code here http://robnapier.net/blog/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol-588.@akshaynhegde